# Java Specific time issue

Tags: java, android

i have small problem with time after midnight. My code looks like this:

```
if (timeActual.after(timeOpen) && timeActual.before(timeClose))
```

and everything is ok untill timeClose is later then 24:00 in 24 hours notation. In this case timeClose will be look like this: 00:01. And that's why second condition of if statment will be false. Anyone know clue?

Comment: After 23:59, even date will change. So I think it should work perfectly

Comment: I use only time without date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only use time, you can do it like this :

```
public class TimeComparator {
    private static final long DIVISOR = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;

    public static int compare(Time t1, Time t2) {
        int v1 = (int)(t1.toMillis(true) % DIVISOR),
            v2 = (int)(t2.toMillis(true) % DIVISOR);

        return v1 - v2;
    }

    public static boolean before(Time t1, Time t2) {
        return compare(t1, t2) < 0;
    }

    public static boolean equals(Time t1, Time t2) {
        return compare(t1, t2) == 0;
    }

    public static boolean after(Time t1, Time t2) {
        return compare(t1, t2) > 0;
    }
}
```

So your condition should look like this :

```
if (TimeComparator.after(timeActual, timeOpen) && TimeComparator.before(timeActual, timeClose))
```